# Capture slide show with recordMyDesktop

Tags: linux

I want to record a presentation using recordMyDesktop from Linux, but when I start the capture of the slide show of presentation the movie remains on application window instead of capturing my presentation. What settings should I change to achieve capture of the presentation?

Comment: Isn't there a setting to record the screen, rather than an application?

Comment: Did you select the correct recording area? http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/rug/p1_2b.php is the recordMyDesktop tutorial page for how to do that.